# jQuery Lightbox Clone is not initialising properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

***Help...?***

Hey, I have the following function on an onClick call:

```
   function addComment() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="colorbox/colorbox-images.css" />'); //this doesn't add correctly.
        jQuery.fn.colorbox({inline:false, href:'boxes/add-comment.html'}); //or it could be this line not importing the page
        return false;
    };
```

However, the STYLESHEET append line doesn't seem to initialise properly. **(NOTE: it may be that the content from "boxes/add-comment.html" aren't being added)** -  Screenshots below:

Comment: Does it make a difference that you're missing a semicolon at the end of the jQuery.noConflict() line?

Comment: Haha, well spotted - alas no, this didn't help either :'(

Comment: No, well, it often isn't that important in Javascript. Still, worth checking. Glad you found your answer in the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was a Float problem in the CSS, something didn't want to play ball.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried,

```
var link = $('<link>');
link.attr({
   'rel':'stylesheet',
   'media':'screen',
   'type':'text/css',
   'href':'colorbox/colorbox-images.css'
});
jQuery('head').append(link);
```

Comment: Curiously, the same thing happens with that code: some bits of the CSS are added, but no content is visible.

Comment: hmmm... weird,... ahmm have you tried doing `jQuery.fn.colorbox({inline:false, href:'boxes/add-comment.html'});` before `jQuery('head').append(link);` ?

Comment: Same result again :'( I'm lost!